# Repository pattern, UoW pattern, plain NHibernate Session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, design-patterns, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

There are many discussions about use of `Repository pattern`, `UoW pattern`. I quite understand when and why `Repository pattern` is used. 
Let's just say I have several aggregate roots. What's next? What pattern/implementation do I prefer? What are the reasons to use more complex solutions than plain NHibernate Session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repository pattern is an abstraction that is -imho- not unnecessary.  It just allows you to predefine certain queries that can be used multiple times throughout the system, and, it improves readability imho.

The repository uses the unit-of-work (which is already implemented by NHibernate's `ISession`); that's my point of view.

What I would do, is create some extension methods on NHibernate's ISession for your project; which can look like this:

```
public class ISessionExtensions
{
    public static IEmployeeRepository GetEmployeeRepository( this ISession session )
    {
         return new EmployeeRepository(session);
    }
}

public class EmployeeRepository()
{
    internal EmployeeRepository( ISession s )
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesFromDepartment( Department d )
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can do this:

```
using( ISession s = _sessionFactory.OpenSession() )
{
    var repository = s.GetEmployeeRepository();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But that would really generate alot of extensions to the nhibernate session if your app has reasonable size. How is that for readability? Nhsession becoming a god class?

Comment: Why would it generate a lot of extensions ?  Even in a system of a reasonable size, I think the number of extension methods wouldn't be that big.  Next to that, it's not that those extension methods are complicated; I do not think they would make ISession a more God class than it already is.

Comment: I thought you meant to create an extension for every repository thus every root aggregate; +1 for saying Isession is already a god class ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Repository pattern is before NHibernate. Now we apply repository pattern on top of NHibernate which is unnecessary abstraction in most cases. The idea behind a generic repository as an abstraction layer over NHibernate is that at some point you can switch to other persisting mechanism like Entity Framework. Really? Is that possible? I think not, because you will end up with so many NH specifics like caching, fetching etc. For me plain Session usage is OK.

[Here ayende talks about that for a while](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/seth/archive/2011/03/09/interview-with-ayende-rahien-aka-oren-eini.aspx)
[And more...](http://ayende.com/blog/4355/responding-to-effectus-commentary)